# typescript - is not assignable to type students

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an error in constructor >> `this.allStudents`

```
class Students {
    public StudentsId: number;
    public StudentsName: string;
    public allStudents?: Students[];
    constructor() {
        this.allStudents = [
            { StudentsId: 100, StudentsName: 'Mahmoud'},
            { StudentsId: 101, StudentsName: 'Sami' },
            { StudentsId: 102, StudentsName: 'Osama' },
            { StudentsId: 103, StudentsName: 'Amer' },
            { StudentsId: 104, StudentsName: 'Ahmad' },
            { StudentsId: 105, StudentsName: 'Fadi' }
        ];
    }

    get getAllStudents() {
        return null;
    }
    getStudentById(_studentsId) {
        return this.allStudents.filter(x => x.StudentsId === _studentsId);
    }
    set addStudent(_student) {

    }


}
```

I don't know why this error is happening. I need some help to solve this issue.

How can I uss this interface in class `students`? Please check interface `IStudents` as below:

```
interface IStudents {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    active:boolean
};
```

Comment: Where is `Students` defined?

Comment: Create an interface `Student` which holds `StudentsId` and `StudentsName`. Then instantiate array of `Student` from your class `Students`

Comment: You are creating an array of Students inside the Students class. That is the error.

Comment: Should `public allStudents?: Students[]` be `public allStudents?: IStudents[]`?

Comment: @JamesMonger no defined take a object of same class

Comment: @Royson how can i do that at another way?!! with same idea

Comment: @JamesMonger , basically, i need to defined array of object as type students and use the interface in any property or method

Comment: @Royson please check my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why you would need a recursive structure of `Students`, so define a `Student` with the properties you are interested in and reference it. It could be a class, interface, or type.

The example below separates the `Student` from the list of `Students`, you may want to change the names to make that more explicit.

```
interface Student {
    StudentsId: number;
    StudentsName: string;
}

class Students {
    public StudentsId: number;
    public StudentsName: string;
    public allStudents: Student[] = [];

    constructor() {
        this.allStudents = [
            { StudentsId: 100, StudentsName: 'Mahmoud'},
            { StudentsId: 101, StudentsName: 'Sami' },
            { StudentsId: 102, StudentsName: 'Osama' },
            { StudentsId: 103, StudentsName: 'Amer' },
            { StudentsId: 104, StudentsName: 'Ahmad' },
            { StudentsId: 105, StudentsName: 'Fadi' }
        ];
    }

    get getAllStudents() {
        return null;
    }

    getStudentById(_studentsId) {
        return this.allStudents.filter(x => x.StudentsId === _studentsId);
    }

    set addStudent(_student) {

    }
}
```

## Hierarchy of Students

If you really need a hierarchy of students, you can achieve that like this:

```
class Students {
    public subStudents: Students[] = [];

    constructor(public StudentsId: number, public StudentsName: string) {
        this.subStudents = [
            new Students(100, 'Mahmoud'),
            new Students(101, 'Sami'),
            new Students(102, 'Osama'),
            new Students(103, 'Amer'),
            new Students(104, 'Ahmad'),
            new Students(105, 'Fadi'),
        ];
    }

    get getAllStudents() {
        return null;
    }
    getStudentById(_studentsId) {
        return this.subStudents.filter(x => x.StudentsId === _studentsId);
    }
    set addStudent(_student) {

    }
}
```

## Optionality of Array Types

I have expressed in both code examples my opinion that a null array is undesirable. You can make it non-optional and instantiate it as an empty array, which removes the need to null-check the array before use.